# Regressing two unit root variables

Tags: time-series

I am supposed to explain the rate of customer defaults by some macroeconomic variables, such as unemployment, GDP growth etc. For simple linear regression, I have promising results:

```
summary(lm(ratio2~lag(unempl,3),data=defaults))

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)    -0.14580    0.25465  -0.573  0.56820   
lag(unempl, 3)  0.15024    0.04763   3.154  0.00211 **
```

However, both of the used variables have unit roots, as confirmed by ADF and KPSS. When I take the first differences, the results are disappointing:

```
summary(lm(diff(ratio2)~diff(values), data = defaults))

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.001313   0.029896   0.044    0.965
diff(values) -0.120137   0.190690  -0.630    0.530
```

I know about spurious regression, but is it justified to ignore it in this case and use the "normal" variables? Or should I stick to the proper way and take first differences?

Comment: Hi: if they are truly I(1), then you're obtaining what is called  "spurious regression" results. so, you need to test for coiintegration and, if the two variables are cointegrated, then that same regression is fine. If they are not cointegrated, it isn't and differences are needed.

Comment: Have you plotted the data? my guess is that there are likely large shifts or outliers in the data that could be driving both relationship between the variables as well as the unit root tests. I would check that in addition to thinking about cointegration.